# Excel - Criar QR Code com dados de 4 celulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, qrcode

Boas,

Estou a tentar criar um documento em Excel que vá buscar os dados inseridos por exemplo (B1, B2, B3, B4) e com estes dados gerar um QrCode. 
Não tenho ainda nenhum software que crie QrCode. Não sei se recomendam algum.

Obrigado

Comment: A pergunta é interessante, mas está mal formatada (ao invés de solicitar dicas/recomendações de software, foque apenas na pergunta principal: como gerar QRCode no Excel). No SOEn tem [essa mesma pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143331/generating-2d-pdf417-or-qr-barcodes-using-excel-vba) e a resposta aponta para este projeto: https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only Não conheço e não testei, mas parece interessante e útil para o que você deseja.

Answer (score 4):

Como eu [comentei anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186452/excel-criar-qr-code-com-dados-de-4-celulas#comment385669_186452), há formas diretas de fazer isso no VBA e o projeto [*Barcode VBA Macro Only* no github](https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only) pode te ajudar. Entretanto, há uma forma bastante simples de conseguir o que você quer, **se o usuário da planilha tiver acesso à Internet**.

Basta usar uma API online [como a do serviço QR Code Generator](http://goqr.me/api/). O seguinte código usa esse serviço para montar uma URL com os parâmetros desejados e obter a imagem diretamente da Internet:

```
Sub GenQRCode(ByVal data As String, ByVal color As String, ByVal bgcolor As String, ByVal size As Integer)
On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Name = "QRCode" Then
            ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    sURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?" + "size=" + Trim(Str(size)) + "x" + Trim(Str(size)) + "&color=" + color + "&bgcolor=" + bgcolor + "&data=" + data
    Debug.Print sURL

    Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sURL + sParameters)
    Set cell = Range("D9")

    With pic
        .Name = "QRCode"
        .Left = cell.Left
        .Top = cell.Top
    End With

End Sub
```

Eu monstei uma planilha pra testar e coloquei as configurações células B3-B7. O botão tem uma macro que chama o código acima da seguinte forma:

```
Sub GenButton_Click()

    GenQRCode Range("B4").Value, Range("B5").Value, Range("B6").Value, Range("B7").Value

End Sub
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A planilha de exemplo pode ser baixada [do 4Shared](https://www.4shared.com/file/FUvqEInPba/QRCode_Simples.html). A API utilizada tem outros parâmetros, que podem ser consultados [na documentação](http://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/).